# Python nested lists and list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-lists

So I'm given a txt file with names and numbers like this:

```
Sam 24
John 30
Rob 44
```

And I need to convert it into a nested list using a list comprehension that looks like this:

```
[["Sam","24"],["John","30]....]
```

(I then plug this into a program that prints it out)

Currently i've gotten this far

```
names = [[name,age] for name in open("people.txt","r").read().split() if name.isalpha()\
         for age in open("people.txt","r").read().split() if age.isdigit()]
```

Basically that gives me kinda what I need, but the second half age part is looping way too much. Any ideas from here? I'm kinda stumped.

Comment: `.read().split()` throws away useful information about the lines. Why not read the file line by line?

Answer (score 5):

You are currently reading the file twice; getting the names in one iteration, and fetching the ages in the second iteration

Instead, this can be done in a single iteration with a simple list comprehension:

```
with open("people.txt","r") as f:
    names = [t.split() for t in f]
```

Comment: `names = [t.split() for t in f]` is even simpler